# How to make the for inner loop more efficient?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and there's this one question that makes me wonder. How to make the for inner loop more efficient in this code?

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.print("Factors of " + i + " is: ");
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0)  System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I was just trying to get the factors of numbers from 2 to 100 but how can i make the inner loop more efficient?

Comment: For starter start `j` with `i/2` and decrement it till `j>1 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit number theory involved here but if you do this it would be efficient specially when the `100` is replaced with something much bigger:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
    System.out.print("Factors of " + i + " is: ");
    for (int j = 2; j <= (int) Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
        if (i % j == 0)  System.out.print(j + " " + i / j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to print i/j as well? If 2 is a factor oft 100,  i/j=50 is also a factor. Also shoudn't the loop run until  j <= (int) ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that for every divisor `a` of `i` there is a number `b` such that `a * b = i`.

Find all divisors `a <= sqrt(i)` and save `b = i/a` and print these values later.

```
final int num = 100;
int[] divisors = new int[(int) Math.sqrt(num)];
for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    System.out.print("Factors of " + i + " is: ");
    int j = 2;
    int index = 0;
    for (; j * j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
            divisors[index++] = i / j;
        }
    }
    if (j * j == i) {
        // print sqrt(i) only once, if it's integral
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    while (--index >= 0) {
        System.out.print(divisors[index] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This way your inner loop needs only `O(sqrt(i))` instead of `O(i)` operations.

Answer (score 0):

This code time complexity  is  `O(N2)`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.print("Factors of " + i + " is: ");
        for (int j = i/2; j > 1; j--) {
            if (i % j == 0)  System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

  }
```

Try this,as your code output will be displayed as follows (ascending order)

```
Factors of 24 is: 2 3 4 6 8 12
```

please be noticed, but this given code will be displayed output as follows (descending order )

```
Factors of 24 is: 12 8 6 4 3 2
```

Comment: The complexity does not change. `O(1+2+...+n) = O(n²) = O(1+2+...+n/2)`. Furthermore this reorders the divisor and prints them in descending order instead of ascending.

Comment: ya,both are inner loops,therefore time complexity will not change,@fabian i adopt your comment :)

Comment: You are not making it more efficient as the questioner asked!